# Creating Custom Git repo with Google Repo

Tags: git, repo

I have created a private repo on bitbucket. The repo contains a `.repo/manifests/default.xml` file, as well as a symlink `.repo/manifest.xml` which points to `default.xml`. The `default.xml` is seen below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>
    <remote name="bitbucket" fetch=".."/>
    <default revision="refs/heads/master" remote="bitbucket" sync-j="4"/>
    <project name="oem" remote="bitbucket" path="oem">
</manifest>
```

I then create a local directory `embedded` and inside it run `repo init -u git@bitbucket.org:<username>/embedded.git`

The above command produces

```
fatal: manifest 'default.xml' not available
fatal: manifest default.xml not found
```

Not sure what i have done wrong?

The repository is currently empty expect for the files mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to find docs on repo.
But if you do a `repo help manifest` it will tell you

> The basic structure of a manifest is a bare Git repository holding a
>   single 'default.xml' XML file in the top level directory.

The symlink `.repo/manifest.xml` and the directory `.repo/manifests` are created by repo and are not part of the manifest repo.
Your git repo should just have a single file `default.xml` (it can have any others that are just ignored by repo).